# Ошибка unexpected indent в последнем рядке bot.polling(none_stop=True)

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

```
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
       if call.message:
            if call.data == 'good':
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)

                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Маргарита", callback_data='Маргарита')
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Пепперони", callback_data='Пепперони')

                markup.add(item1, item2)
            
            elif call.data == 'bad':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, '...')
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Вот у вас есть `try:`, а где `except:` или `finally:`?

Comment: Спасибо........

Comment: Пожалуйста, оформите сами ответ с решением проблемы в вопросе :)

Answer (score 0):

Сформировал ответ от [@gil9red](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1238443/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-unexpected-indent-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b5-bot-pollingnone-stop-true#comment2172433_1238443)

```py
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
       if call.message:
            if call.data == 'good':
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)

                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Маргарита", callback_data='Маргарита')
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Пепперони", callback_data='Пепперони')

                markup.add(item1, item2)
            
            elif call.data == 'bad':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, '...')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error: {e}')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```